# set double type array values in java

Tags: java, jpa

I have a JPA entity with

```
package com.vivo.entities;
public class Lv_work_item {
  double[] aRBal = new double[10];
  public double[] getaRBal() {
    return aRBal;
  }
  public void setaRBal(double[] aRBal) {
   this.aRBal = aRBal;
  }
}
```

And i have to set this aRBal values with double type in JAVA class. How can i set the values to it & get the values from it?

In my JAVA class i coded like...

```
Lv_work_item lvwork = new Lv_work_item();
double[] aRBa = new double[10]; 
    for(int i=0;i<=10;i++){
      aRBa[i]=0.0;
   lvwork.setaRBal(aRBa);
   System.out.println(lvwork.getaRBal().toString()+""+aRBa[i]);
}
```

But how can i set the values and values come as garbage values from lvwork.getaRBal()

Comment: you have set them and got them? I don't understand what you are asking?? you set the value of aRBal with lvwork.setaRBal???

Comment: i want get the every index value.....what i want index value how get that index value.

Comment: Do you want to display this array value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get array value by iterate index, such as :

```
    double[] array = { 1, 2, 3 };
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(array[i]);
    }
```

Comment: double[] array =Arrays.toString(lvwork.getCusts());                            for(int i=0;i<10;i++){sysout(array[i]);}                 this is correct or not...........

Comment: according to my requirements......i tested i written lines are correct.....thanks ur reply...